# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length exception

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

this is part of my code my code:

```
  Connection dbcon=null;
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    ResultSetMetaData metadata;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());         
        }
    try {
       dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Bus_Info");
       stm = dbcon.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery("select distinct number, name, min(Stop_Times.departure_time), max(Stop_Times.departure_time) from Routes, Stop_Times, Stops, trips, Calendar where(stops.stop_name like'ΣΟΝΙΑ' and Stops.stop_id=Stop_Times.stop_id and Stop_Times.trip_id=trips.trip_id and trips.route_id=Routes.route_id and trips.direction='outbound' and sunday=1 and Calendar.service_id=trips.service_id)group by number, name");

        metadata = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = metadata.getColumnCount();
    System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", "ΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ ΓΡΑΜΜΗΣ",
                          "ΟΝΟΜΑ ΓΡΑΜΜΗΣ", "ΧΡΟΝΟΣ ΔΥΙΕΛΕΣΗΣ ΠΡΩΤΟΥ ΔΡΟΜΟΛΟΓΙΟΥ",
                          "ΧΡΟΝΟΣ ΔΙΕΛΕΥΣΗΣ ΤΕΛΕΥΤΑΙΟΥ ΔΡΟΜΟΛΟΓΙΟΥ");
    System.out.println();

    while(rs.next()) {

        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", rs.getString("number"), rs.getString("name"),
                         rs.getString("min(Stop_Times.departure_time)"),
                         rs.getString("max(Stop_Times.departure_time") );

    }
    rs.close();
    stm.close();
        dbcon.close(); 

} catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print("SQLException: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

the problem here is that when i want to display two or more columns, i get this message:

"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length exception "

what am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I think for unicode characters you need to use `N''` notation, like this: `like N'ΣΟΝΙΑ'`

Comment: i tried this, but it doesnt have to do with this exception

Comment: Why are you using rs.getstring on a date column? Didn't you want to use getdate? Alternatively you can convert your min and max dates in the SQL statement

Answer (score 3):

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation.

It shouldn't have to do with how many columns you are trying to print. It just doesn't like the format of at least one of the strings you are fetching. Try to print only the name column and see if it works. If not, then it's probably not being decoded correctly.

If this is the case, go to your ODBC Data Source Administrator, select the relevant Driver from User DSN or System DSN, click on Configure and change the encoding there. If that doesn't work, try updating/downgrading your Driver. (I have had the same issue and updating my 4D Driver from v13 to v14 fixed it).

Answer (score 1):

this is a java bug, update to java 1.7.60 at least

Comment: Any documentation of this?

Comment: I dont have any documentation. In Pc with 64 bit execute query againt Access and it show me this error. Only upgrade java 1.7.17 to 1.7.70 and this works

Comment: I updated to 7 update 67 but I'm still having this issue. Where do you get 7 update 70 from?

Comment: Definitelly the error itself is not java bug, it happens inside the driver even if you use other languages to access the ODBC datasource.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with 64-bit Java 7 update 67. It's working for me on a different 32-bit machine using the same version of the JRE. It might work to switch to the 32 bit JRE.

The 32 bit Access 2010 ODBC driver cannot be installed if you have 64 bit Office installed, so I can't try the 32 bit JVM on the same machine.